# Rails 3 Active Record object re-initialize

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have an old user object and a new user object.
I'm trying to create a new User object and want to assign all the attributes to the old user object and keep the id (primary key) same without creating a new row in the User table.

```
old_user = User.find(20)
old_user.id # this is 20
old_user.name # this displays "old_name"
new_user = User.new
new_user.name = "new_name"
old_user = new_user
old_user.save # this doesn't work since the new_user.id is nil and so is old_user.id is nil
old_user.id = 20 and save #this won't work either.
```

How can I save the state of new_user to old_user object but maintain the same primary key id.

Comment: Why do you need to create a new user? Can't you just update the attributes of old_user?

Comment: Because, new_user has a lot of attributes and associations, it would make sense to save the state of new_user to old_user rather than updating old_user

Comment: there was a answer which helped me but it got removed or was removed, it was by V something

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell by your question, you don't need a new user object. There are several ways to update attributes on an ActiveRecord object:

```
user = User.find(20)
user.name = "new_name"
user.save # returns true if successful
```

You can pass in a hash to update several attributes at once:

```
user = User.find(20)
user.update_attributes(name: "new_name", email: "new_email@email.com")
```

Comment: Thanks, I know I can do user.name = "new_name" but is it possible to pass new_user to update_attributes? like user.update_attributes(new_user.attributes)

Comment: Maybe you should tell us a bit about your use case. Why are you creating a new user?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is pretty easy to answer, but like Zach Kemp says above, you should describe your use case so perhaps someoene can suggest a better way to do what you want.

Anyway, this will do what you want.

```
old_user = User.find(20)
new_user = User.new(old_user.attributes)
new_user.save!
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is what you want, the clone method in ruby does the trick. It will also clone the id

```
new_user = old_user.clone
```